# Are there any Open Source (Also Free) GeoBI solution?

Tags: business-intelligence

I am searching for a BI suite with Geo capability.

1. It should have basic function like showing spatial data from spatial database like postgres/sqlserver etc (Qgis like feature)
2. It should have dashboard functionality (also in real time).
3. It Should be able to create thematic map of different kinds (point,region ranges etc)

I want to know this before I start coding on my own?

Solution I have gone throught:

1. Petaho
2. Jasper

Answer (score 1):

We are developing such a solution and the beta is available at

https://github.com/mapsjs/OI2

We anticipate being code-complete with some documentation by the end of the month but there's enough there now to test-drive.

This runs on top of MapDotNet, download at http://www.mapdotnet.com/index.php/trial-downloads

MapDotNet can connect to numerous back-ends including PostGIS.  MapDotNet runs on Windows.  The "60-day trial" will downgrade to our free "Express" product at the end of 60 days, the only difference is that "Express" runs only two render/query threads.  Simulate this by finding

```
<add key="WorkDispatcherPoolSize" value="16" />
```

in the web.config file and setting value="2".

Comment: is there online demo? I am writing a tool myself using JSF + openlayers + jQuery etc. I don't this OI2 is completly free since it depends on MapDotNet.

Comment: MapDotNet is free in Express mode with a core use limit as noted.  No demos they'll let me show you yet but I'll post some screenshots later this morning.

Comment: Looks like our official beta release will be next week, along with a MapDotNet release that will be a prerequisite.  I'll let you know when those things happen.

Comment: waiting for the demo :) Thanx.